# Chrome does not fully render shadow unless hovering onto it

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am having some weird issue with Chrome rendering the shadow box.
    https://jsfiddle.net/8urkLkyf/10/

```
.bubble {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;
    margin-left:89px;
    margin-right:89px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

When you open the accordio, the message bubbles should have shadows around it.
[image]
But when it is opened, it is not rendered, but when you hover on the user name or something, the shadow will show.

This is not happening under firefox..
The code was originally borrowed from:
[How can I fix this alignment with CSS when using bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386051/how-can-i-fix-this-alignment-with-css-when-using-bootstrap)

Update: 
I found a similar issue, but not yet get to work it the same as mine:
[CSS box shadow conflicting with pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304564/css-box-shadow-conflicting-with-pseudo-element)

Comment: I tried by removing `.bubble::before {
    content:"\00a0";
 }` and it works, but I still need the pointing arrow.

Comment: I filed a bug report to Chome and they are there to fix this issue. It seems to be a Chrome bug.https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=534450